# How to print in the Python programming language

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a new learner to the Python language. When I want to print, I use the syntax:

```
print "hello world"
```

But when I use this syntax, it shows an error like missing parenthesis in calling print. I don't know why it is happening, because I know there is no need of using parentheses in Python to print a string like

```
print ("hello world")
```

What wrong have I done?

This is the error I get:

> SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

Comment: try `print ("hello world")` in python 3.x print is a function not a statement

Comment: Probably you are using python 3.x.  Try `python --version` in terminal to be  sure.

Comment: "I know there is no need of using parenthesis" - "Missing parenthesis"

Comment: When the interpreter told you that you need parentheses for a print call, did you think it was playing a practical joke on you or something?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, OP knew what is the right answer, he didn't know why this is the right answer. Probably, OP doesn't know the differences between python 2.x and 3.x. `did you think it was playing a practical joke on you or something?`- that phrase is unnecessarily rude and will demoralize new users to ask a question, though we can agree on the point that the question lacks research effort.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque - I think it's pretty clear that the OP is sure that he doesn't need parentheses on a `print()` call even though the interpreter says that he does. And I wasn't trying to be rude - many people really don't believe the interpreter, generally when it tells them it can't find a file with the specified name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
print "hello world"
```

The above statement is OK when you are using Python 2.x, because in Python 2.x, `print` is a statement.

But in Python 3.x, **print** is a function and there is no way to turn it back into a statement. So you must use parentheses.

So for Python 3.x, the answer is:

```
print("hello world")
```

Please refer to: *[Print Is A Function](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function)*.